# Angular.js: choosing a pre-compiled template depending on a condition

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

[disclaimer: I've just a couple of weeks of angular behind me]

In the angular app I'm trying to write, I need to display some information and let the user edit it provided they activated a switch. The corresponding HTML is:

```
    <span ng-hide="editing" class="uneditable-input" ng:bind='value'>
    </span>
    <input ng-show="editing" type="text" name="desc" ng:model='value' value={{value}}>
```

where `editing` is a boolean (set by a switch) and `value` the model.

I figured this is the kind of situation directives are designed for and I've been trying to implement one. The idea is to precompile the `<span>` and the `<input>` elements, then choose which one to display depending on the value of the `editing` boolean. Here's what I have so far:

```
angular.module('mod', [])
.controller('BaseController',
  function ($scope) {
    $scope.value = 0;
    $scope.editing = true;
  })
.directive('toggleEdit',
  function($compile) {
    var compiler = function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch("editflag", function(){
            var content = '';
            if (scope.editflag) {
                var options='type="' + (attrs.type || "text")+'"';
                if (attrs.min) options += ' min='+attrs.min;
                options += ' ng:model="' + attrs.ngModel
                          +'" value={{' + attrs.ngModel +'}}';
                content = '<input '+ options +'></input>';
            } else {
                content = '<span class="uneditable-input" ng:bind="'+attrs.ngModel+'"></span>';
            };
            console.log("compile.editing:" + scope.editflag);
            console.log("compile.attrs:" + angular.toJson(attrs));
            console.log("compile.content:" + content);
            })
    };
    return {
        require:'ngModel',
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            editflag:'='
            },
        link: compiler
    }
});
```

(the whole html+js is available [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/K6RuT7AGwEI6AA9CGlPK)).

Right now, the directive doesn't do anything but output some message on the console. How do I replace a `<toggle-edit ...>` element of my html with the `content` I define in the directive? If I understood the doc correctly, I should compile the `content` before linking it: that'd be the `preLink` method of the directive's `compile`, right ? But how do I implement it in practice ?

---

Bonus question: I'd like to be able to use this `<toggle-edit>` element with some options, such as:

```
<toggle-edit type="text" ...></toggle-edit>
<toggle-edit type="number" min=0 max=1 step=0.01></toggle-edit>
```

I could add tests on the presence of the various options (like I did for `min` in the example above), but I wondered whether there was a smarter way, like putting all the `attrs` but the `ngModel` and the `editflag` at once when defining the template ?

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial by John Lindquist that shows how to do what you want. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nKJDHnXaKTY

Here is his code:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.directive('jlMarkdown', function () {
    var converter = new Showdown.converter();
    var editTemplate = '<textarea ng-show="isEditMode" ng-dblclick="switchToPreview()" rows="10" cols="10" ng-model="markdown"></textarea>';
    var previewTemplate = '<div ng-hide="isEditMode" ng-dblclick="switchToEdit()">Preview</div>';
    return{
        restrict:'E',
        scope:{},
        compile:function (tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
            var markdown = tElement.text();

            tElement.html(editTemplate);
            var previewElement = angular.element(previewTemplate);
            tElement.append(previewElement);

            return function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.isEditMode = true;
                scope.markdown = markdown;

                scope.switchToPreview = function () {
                    var makeHtml = converter.makeHtml(scope.markdown);
                    previewElement.html(makeHtml);
                    scope.isEditMode = false;
                }
                scope.switchToEdit = function () {
                    scope.isEditMode = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/moderndegree/cRXr6/

Comment: Thanks for the link to the tutorial, it's quite helpful. Basically, the solution you propose is to *not* choose the template, but output a  template whose elements can be hidden on demand. That's an idea. Still, as the `compile` function has no scope yet, the parent model isn't accessible when the template is created. How can I link the template to the parent model?